# How do you check whether a CSV file is corrupted in PHP and/or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, csv

I'm making an HTML5/jQuery/PHP app which involves uploading CSV files (via a drag and drop), and processing them to a MySQL database. So far, I can upload the files, and I know how to read them into a database.

**My question:** I am wondering if it is possible to detect whether a CSV file is in a corrupted format by PHP or Javascript/jQuery? For example, I can rename somefile.png (an image) to somefile.csv, and it still gets uploaded. If I open up the renamed file in Notepad++, all I see is garbage, which is expected.

I would like to do this on the clientside, so I can alert the user (via JQuery) whether the file is in a corrupted format. I'd also like to check on the serverside (via PHP) before I start iterating over each CSV file for db processing.

My first thoughts would be to use regular expressions, but I am unsure how to make ones for this particular problem. I know the basics of regular expressions, but haven't really used them in advanced settings before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should check content-type of picked file, it should be "text/csv". At the server-side you can check file via fgetscsv PHP function (http://php.net/manual/function.fgetcsv.php) (catch null or false on error)

Comment: I'm already using fgetcsv on the CSV files... If I was to process the CSV in a try-catch block, what exceptions could I catch? I'm also checking the content-type via jQuery and AJAX.

Comment: I mean that you can detect if fgetcsv returns false instead of array of values. False is signalize that file data is incorrect.

Comment: I had a closer look at the function on the main PHP site, and sounds like their "Example #1 Read and print the entire contents of a CSV file" example demonstrates what you're saying. I'm using a combination of curl and fgetcsv, but will change my code to suit.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to be validating it if you're going to be reading it right after. Just read it in and catch any errors as you read. That way you come to know whether file is valid or corrupt.